# Excel extract minimum and maximum numbers when cell has multiple numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When multiple numbers are entered in a single cell, is there a way that Excel can detect the largest and smallest numbers and output them into two different cells?

I am creating a dimensional spreadsheet in Excel that lists dimensions and calculates tolerance limits. Yet there is an issue when the given dimension lists two different values. As seen here (dimensional example):

[image: dimensional example]

Since this form can be used by multiple individuals, information can be entered in a variety of formats.

What I have currently is the following:

[image: Visual Example]

- B8 for the given dimension (*can be entered as
  `1.257 1.258`
  `1.257,1.258`
  `1.257 - 1.258`
  `1.257(Alt+Enter)1.258` the order of largest and smallest number is not guaranteed.*)
- C8 for lower tolerance
- D8 for upper tolerance
- E8 for calculated lower dimension`=IF(C8="MIN",B8,IF(C8="","",ROUNDUP(B8-ABS(C8),4)))` *elaborate formula for `=B8-C8` goal is to output minimum number `1.257`*
- F8 for calculated upper dimension `=IF(D8="MAX",B8,IF(D8="","",ROUNDDOWN(B8+ABS(D8),4)))` *elaborate formula for `=B8+C8` goal is to output maximum number `1.258`*

Comment: Is VB acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your double dimension is in `A1` you could try:

For maximum:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," "),","," "),CHAR(10)," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(.<//*)][.*0=0]")
```

For minimum:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," "),","," "),CHAR(10)," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.<//*][.*0=0]")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to get this running in my formulas.