# EXCEL =FILTERXML() Formula Error with Non Decimal Numbers

Tags: excel, xml, excel-formula

Had a previous question here regarding the extraction of multiple numbers from a cell. It was answered yet I encountered an issue with the xml script/ formula in Excel.

[Excel extract minimum and maximum numbers when cell has multiple numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104598/excel-extract-minimum-and-maximum-numbers-when-cell-has-multiple-numbers/68104723#68104723)

Currently an error appears when a natural number is entered as the lower value when typed into B2. The formula works when it is typed as a decimal (rational), 0, or as a negative (integer and rational). If a positive number is written without a decimal, the formula outputs a `#SPILL!` and `#VALUE!` errors. (`#SPILL!` due to outputting the lower number correctly, yet tries to dump the larger number in the cell below)

[Example of Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwapH.png)

Is there 1) A solution for this error? and 2) Any sources I can reference to better understand this XML format? Tried to research this myself but the `"//s[.<//*][.*0=0]"` part of the formula is really throwing me off.

Formula for extracting smaller value:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B10,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.<//*][.*0=0]")),"0",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B10,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.<//*][.*0=0]"))
```

Formula for extracting larger value:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B10,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(.<//*)][.*0=0]")
```

Answer (score 2):

With new functions come better answers; have a go with:

```
=MAX(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ",",","-","
"},,1))
```

Hard to show on formula here but between the 1st & 2nd line is a linefeed char. If you don't know how to input that then get your cursor next to the opening quotes of the elemnt and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Swap out `MAX()` for `MIN()` to get the minimum value.

---

A source for the linked answer and `FILTERXML()` could potentially be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194). About the error: I do to now get the error where I'd not get that beforehand. So not sure what update this function got (if any) behind the scenes but it seems to be the `[.*0=0]` part which would only check if node is numeric that is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful in getting the formula up and running again. The link for the XML makes things a lot clearer in the original formula.